# Symfony2 Add images with file field + removing

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have entity and form for ad creating. Form has Photos field(`FileType::class`). When I edit Ad, I want to view uploaded photos and remove them from Ad.

But I have idea, and I don't know if it's bad or good. Idea:

> On edit form view images. Add to form hidden fields with photo id. If
>   I remove photo, javascript remove hidden field with some photo id. On
>   form submit I will check list of photos and list of hidden fields for
>   photo, and remove photo where hidden field is not exists.

Maybe you can give me better propositions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using embedding collection of forms. There is an example on Symfony site which manage tags of post and tags items are dynamic. 
I think it can be useful in your case. 
This link to cookbook with example of solution http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Yes, it's nice idea, but I cant understand how I can remove photos. For example: Open url with Ad form and add new ad. Then open this for for edit. All file input fields are empty and I can only add NEW photos. I dont understand logic for removing photos =|